# Selenium how to wait until images are fully loaded

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to get all the the img-src attributes from the product image carrousel here: https://www.homedepot.com.mx/electrico/placas-y-dimmers/placas-decorativas/tapa-i-tipo-quinzino-apag-sencillo-461027

I already have the code to get all the src attributes, and it works "fine", but not always... sometimes the pictures take a little while to load, and when this happens, even if the img tags are correctly found, they don't have a src attribute yet, and so I get an error.

If I add a time.sleep(), it helps, but is not failproof and if the page somehow takes longer to load the pics, I still get the error.

I tried waiting for the "div", {"data-test": "carousel-wrapper"} wrapper tag to exist and be clickable, however this didn't work as even if the wrapper tag exists, the img tags could still be without src attribute. Even waiting for the img tags doesn't work, because they could already exist, but without a src attribute.

Is there a method to always wait until the product pics load in the carrousel (i.e: the src attribute exists and is filled)?

This a snippet of my code where I currently read the img src:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

options = Options()
options.set_preference("dom.webnotifications.enabled", False)
options.set_preference("dom.push.enabled", False)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

driver.get("https://www.homedepot.com.mx/electrico/placas-y-dimmers/placas-decorativas/tapa-i-tipo-quinzino-apag-sencillo-461027")

prod_soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")

pics_json = ""
pictures = []
pictures_container = prod_soup.find(
    "div", {"data-test": "carousel-wrapper"}
)
if pictures_container:
    picture_tags = pictures_container.find_all("img")
    if picture_tags:
        max_pictures = 0
        for pic_tag in picture_tags:
            try:
                pictures.append(pic_tag["src"])
            except Exception as ex:
                print(ex)
            max_pictures = max_pictures + 1
            if max_pictures >= 6:
                break

        pics_json = json.dumps(pictures)

print(pics_json)
```

Comment: If possible then share your working code and add an example scenario

Comment: sure thing! Just a added a snippet of my working code... as I said, it works, but only when the pictures load right away (and sometimes they don't)

Comment: Check if this xpath is viable for elements in the developer console. //div[contains(@data-test,'carousel')]//img[@Itemprop]

Comment: yep, it does find the img tags... is there a way to make sure it waits for these img tags to have something in the scr attribute?